# Is creation of quark-gluon plasma endothermic?

Tags: quark-gluon-plasma, relativistic-jets

When we create quark-gluon plasma in a lab by colliding lead nuclei, does releasing the nuclear bonds give us energy? Or take it?

An astrophysical jet could be as hot as 10 trillion K:

https://www.space.com/32467-black-hole-jets-hotter-than-expected.html

If any atom got in its way, it would be turned in to QGP, right? Would that cool the jets?

Comment: When two or more particles are bound together that means they are interacting with each other and have a binding energy which is negative, in order to separate them you would need negative of that binding energy thus you would need to give positive energy. So if you're converting an atom into QGP then energy would be required and this energy would be coming from the jet particle system as a whole.